# script/command needed to list down all header files (.h files) in a directory (recursively)

Tags: list, unix, search, grep, ls

given a base directory  
I would like to recursively list down all the header files under all directories below it
/*

And if possible, I would like the output to be something like:

```
headerfile:  <path 1>
             <path 2>
             ...
headerfile2: <path a>
             <path b> etc
```

Whats the best way of doing it. I tried playing around with ls -R and grep, but i am fairly new to scripting.

Comment: Can you get more specific regarding the output format?

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -name "*.h"
```

for just the paths in the current dir and below. And if you can live with repeating the filename, and assuming I understood what you want as output, this is the more complex version...

```
find . -name "*.h" | while read i; do echo $(basename "$i") "$i"; done | sort
```

Comment: Some Unixes might require a `-print` option at the end of the `find` command.